# Minimal polynomial in a quotient

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

Let $M=\mathbb{Q}[x]/(\phi_5)$, and $\beta=x+x^4 \mod (\phi_5)\in M$
where $\phi_5=x^4+x^3+x^2+x+1$

I am trying to find the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$.

I know that M is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Q}(a)$, where $a$ is a root of $\phi_5$.
But I have no idea how to use this isomorphism.

According to Matt, we have that the minimal polynomial of $\beta$ over $\mathbb{Q}$ is $x^2+x-1$.
But how do I find the minimal polynomial of $s=x \mod \phi_5$ over $\mathbb{Q}(\beta)$.

Thank you!

Comment: $x^2-x\beta+1=0$. You figure this stuff out by just playing around. I think that's probably the minimal polynomial.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that $x^5=1$ in $M$. Thus
$$\beta^2=2+x^2+x^3$$
so
$$\beta^2+\beta-1=1+x+x^2+x^3+x^4=0$$